# Internet Explorer 11 executes ajax success condition but then freezes

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11, freeze

Internet Explorer 11 seems to execute my ajax call successfully. It runs the code under the `success` condition all the way up to the last line in that block, updates the HTML DOM structure, but then freezes after that. 
The error I get in IE is: " is not responding due to a long-running script".

**My code works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari!**

Here's how I call function `loadContentviaAjax` when a user clicks a pagination link:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination-top a', function () {
    //CODE      
    loadContentviaAjax($(this).attr('href'), rawNewURL);
    console.log('20');
    return false;
});
```

Here's part of the codeblock in `companysearch.js` it concerns:

```
function loadContentviaAjax(furl, rawNewURL) {
    var webserviceURL = rawNewURL;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: webserviceURL,
        data: "",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {
            $("#loadstatus").html($("#whoops").attr('data-message')).addClass('box_error');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('0');

            //MORE OF MY CODE

            console.log('18'); //<-- this line is still logged
        } 
    });                 
return false
}
```

I tried:
- commenting out all code in the `success` block of my AJAX call
- tried settings breakpoints in IE Developer Tools

but I can't narrow it down to the line that causes this issue.

The line

```
console.log('20');
```

is also hit, so IE freezes after that, but apart from the `loadContentviaAjax` I can't narrow down what is causing the freeze....please help!

Comment: That `19` should be logged before the `0` and `10`

Comment: @epascarello: ah, of course, you're right :) However, I now stepped into the code but still, my script is freezing IE right after completing the `success` block. Any ideas?

Comment: If you comment out the code in the block, does it freeze? Does it fire off any other asynchronous processes? What triggered the Ajax call to begin with?

Comment: Yes, even when I comment everything out it freezes. I now think it has to do with an earlier issue I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873953/internet-explorer-11-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-json-file

I now also noticed that the logging inside the `success` block is only executed when Iset the contenttype of the called webservice to `text/plain`, which is undesirable. Any suggestions there perhaps? :)

Comment: How big is the JSON? Is the JSON valid?

Comment: @epascarello: just to be sure I validated the JSON here and it's valid. You think the response length might be a problem for IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright! I found the piece of code that's causing the hang in IE11. I'm not quite sure how you're going to fix it, but I figured you would want to know.

Setting up the js debugger before clicking the link, and then pausing execution shows javascript to be spending all of its time in http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js . So your code has little to do with it.

Stepping through indicates that Google's code is somehow stuck in an infinite loop jumping from function a to b to c to function a again. It spends most of the time in the catch block for a call to getBoundingClientRect on an iframe that has no parent (throws Unspecified Error).

When I keep http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js from downloading using Fiddler, your navigation works fine.

I wish I could just tell you to "change this or that and it will work", but I can't find it - minified Google code is hard to debug. Is it possible your code is leaving the google ads container orphaned somehow?

Comment: I would like to add to your answer.. if possible use a closure and locally assign your variables, perhaps something in your code is conflicting in a global namespace causing the behavior mentioned above. .. just a thought.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will look into that. Just a question as I never use IE for debugging, would you mind posting the steps you took to setup the js debugger? So which codelines did you watch etc.? Thanks and I will post back asap :)

Comment: Aaaah. The Magic of IE. Steps:
- 1) Open IE
- 2) Press F12 (Menu - Tools - F12 Developer tools works too)
- 3) Press the little bug looking pic on the left

The folder icon opens the list of scripts. Just press the pause button after clicking the link to see what's going on.

Comment: IE has a little bonus due to being M$. This prob won't help with the google scripts but yeah.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel: that was it! My javascript was replacing Google AdSense script tags. When I moved this scripts outside of the div I was altering via javascript all is well again! I'll award the bounty when I can :)